# Does every ring of integers sit inside a ring of integers that has a power basis?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Given a finite extension of the rationals, $K$, we know that $K=\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ by the primitive element theorem, so every $x \in K$ has the form

$$x = a_0 + a_1 \alpha + \cdots + a_n \alpha^n,$$

with $a_i \in \mathbb{Q}$.

However, the ring of integers, $\mathcal{O}_K$, of $K$ need not have a basis over $\mathbb{Z}$ which consists of $1$ and powers of a single element (a power basis). In fact, there exist number fields which require an arbitrarily large number of elements to form such a basis.

> **Question:** Can every ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ that does not have a power basis be extended to a ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_L$ which does have a power basis, for some finite $L/K$?

Comment: Every $abelian$ number field $K$ sits inside $\mathbb Q(\zeta)$ for some root of unity $\zeta$ and has a ring of integers $\mathbb Z[\zeta]$. So your question is answered in the positive for abelian $K/\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Just a remark on terminology: If $\mathcal O_K=\mathbb Z[\alpha]$, then $\mathcal O_K$ is sometimes called *monogenic*.

Comment: I think this question should really be reposted on MathOverflow. Also, before tackling the number field case, it's probably worth thinking about curves over a field: given a base curve $C$ and an affine open set $U$, say that $C_1\to C$ (ramified covering) is "monogenic" for these data when there is $f$ regular on $U_1:=U\times_C C_1$ such that $\mathcal{O}(U_1)=\mathcal{O}(U)[f]$. Is it true that there is always $C_2\to C_1$ that is monogenic? (Maybe this is stupidly true or false, I'm not sure. But it could be easier to think about.)

Comment: This has now been [asked on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/238037/does-every-ring-of-integers-sit-inside-a-monogenic-ring-of-integers)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen and sadly it's not had much luck there either!

Comment: Note a similar result holds for the ordinals. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Cantor_normal_form

Comment: What is a ring of integers? Merely a ring containing only integers?

Comment: I honestly don't understand your remark "In fact, there exist number fields which require an arbitrarily large number of elements to form such a basis.": rings of integers are $\mathbb Z$-modules, so all their $\mathbb Z$-bases have the same number of elements (namely the degree of the corresponding field extension).

Comment: What I should say is this: The number of generators of a ring of integers, as an algebra, can be 1 (monogenic) or arbitrarily large.

Comment: @Jacob Wakem, if you take a field extension, let's say $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{Q}$, then the ring of integers (of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$) refers in some sense to the 'analogon' of what $\mathbb{Z}$ is to $\mathbb{Q}$. In this case the ring of integers would be $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$. But I hope my comment is not misleading, because if $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}$ is a field extension, then the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is not necessarily(!) $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.

Comment: The difficulty in finding a general approach to construct such an extension arises from the fact that the structure of the ring of integers can be quite complicated, and power bases may not always exist for every number field.

Answer (score -8):

the ring of integers of the quadratic field Q(sqrt(2)) has a power basis {1, sqrt(2)}. However, not every ring of integers has a power basis.

consider the ring of integers of a number field that has no real embeddings. For example, let K be the number field Q(sqrt(-5)), which has degree 2 over Q and no real embeddings. The ring of integers of K is Z[(1+sqrt(-5))/2], which has no power basis.

suppose that {a,b} is a power basis for Z[(1+sqrt(-5))/2]. Then every element of Z[(1+sqrt(-5))/2] can be written as a polynomial in a and b with integer coefficients. Since a and b are algebraic integers, their conjugates are also algebraic integers. But the Galois group of K over Q acts transitively on the roots of the minimal polynomial of a and b, so every element of Z[(1+sqrt(-5))/2] has the same set of conjugates. Therefore, the only way to write an element of Z[(1+sqrt(-5))/2] as a polynomial in a and b with integer coefficients is to use the same coefficients for every conjugate, which is not always possible.

the ring of integers of K has no power basis, and therefore cannot be embedded into a ring of integers with a power basis.

Comment: Looks like more chatGPT nonsense...

Comment: I see my error , not all rings of integers  have a power basis, sorry.

Comment: Also you can think I used chatGPT, but I didn’t. Frankly I didn’t even know it could solve equations

Comment: 1) The ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ since $-5 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$. And $\{1, \sqrt{-5}\}$ is a power basis for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. 2) You haven't attempted to answer the question. The OP clearly states that not every ring of integers has a power basis. The question is if there is a further extension of $K$ whose ring of integers has a power basis. Your last sentence claims that this is impossible with no proof.

Comment: I see that. I haven’t answered the question correctly and wasted your time, sorry.